# ipython complaining about readline

Tags: python

When I install ipython on my osx and run it, I get the following warning:

```
 /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/
 site-packages/IPython/utils/rlineimpl.py:96:
 RuntimeWarning: Leopard libedit detected - readline will not be wel
 behaved including some crashes on tab completion, and incorrect
 history navigation. It is highly recommended that you install
 readline, which is easy_installable with: 'easy_install readline'
```

I have have installed readline, and do not use the system python that was originally installed in `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python$`. The `/usr/bin/python` points to version 2.7 as shown below

```
uname -a
Darwin macbook.local 10.8.0 Darwin Kernel Version 10.8.0: Tue Jun  7 
16:33:36 PDT 2011; root:xnu-1504.15.3~1/RELEASE_I386 i386

$sudo pip install readline ipython

$ipython --version
0.11

$/usr/bin/python --version # 
Python 2.7.1 

$which python
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python
```

I have read the question in [Python sys.path modification not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1017909/python-sys-path-modification-not-working) - I added `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/readline-6.2.1-py2.7.egg-info` to the  `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/ipython` so that it now looks like this: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=dVnxufbS

but I cannot figure out why I am getting the following error:

```
File
"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/ipython",
line 9
sys.path.insert(0,"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/
python2.7/site-packages/readline-6.2.1-py2.7.egg-info")
```

I do not think the above path is an issue, and my goal is to get ipython to working without complaining about readline even though it is installed and imports correctly.

Comment: Tab completion does work when I go into ipython inspite of the warning message. So perhaps this means that I can ignore the warning?

Comment: After looking at this a little more, I came across the a post http://bradmontgomery.net/blog/fix-leopard-libedit-detected/ that solved my problem.. I had to run "easy_install -a readline" and that made python read the latest installation of readline and this got rid of the problem. More details here:https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/python-virtualenv/BEQAurh9EZw/discussion. I am not sure how to close out this questions since I have found my own answer.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

When pip installs readline, it will never be imported, because readline.so goes in site-packages, which ends up behind the libedit System one, located in `lib-dynload` (OSX Python path order is very odd).  `easy_install -a readline` will actually install usable readline.

So you can either use easy_install, or use pip and muck about with your PYTHONPATH/sys.path (which essentially means: DO NOT USE PIP).

A bit more detail on the IPython list (though there really isn't anything IPython-specific about this issue): http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/ipython-user/2011-September/008426.html

EDIT: extra note about virtualenv.

There is a bug in virtualenv < 1.8.3, where readline would not be properly staged when you create an env.

Comment: Note to future readers of this answer: if you've already tried `pip install readline` and that didn't work, you'll actually need to do `easy_install -a readline`.  Without the -a, it looks like easy_install will realize that you've already got a pip-installed readline, and not do anything.  The -a forces it to do a full re-install.

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution, along with all others on SO didn't work for me :( I've removed `readline`, re-installed it, uninstalled `iPython` until readline was reinstalled, done it in a virtualenv, done it without, used `easy_install-2.7`, etc., etc., etc. - I'm running OS X 10.8.2. If anyone has achieved this using OS X 10.8.2 (stupid Apple), would you mind @-ing me with the solution.

Comment: @orokusaki yup, I can confirm that `easy_install -a readline` works on 10.8.2.  If  you are in a virtualenv, you need to make sure you have virtualenv ≥ 1.8.3 (11/2012), which fixes an issue where readline would not be included in your envs.

Comment: @minrk - thanks. I discovered the cause for my troubles; while I was easy_installing `readline` properly, I was still installing iPython in a virtualenv (I usually do that, just to segregate non-essential tools from my global Python install) - when I deactivated my virtualenv and pip installed iPython globally it worked

Comment: @minrk - it may be worth changing the ipython startup message to include the `-a`.

Comment: In my case, I was running `ipython` in a virtualenv; apparently, I must also then run `easy_install -a readline` in that virtualenv as well.

Comment: Actually this is a mess on Mavericks once again. I'm tired of this situation and installed bpython.

Comment: And this is a mess, because easy_install tries to install Python readline package 6.2.4.1 (not the latest 6.3.3!), which tries to build with gcc-4.0, which isn't supported on Mac OS X 10.9!

I'm getting really tired of this situation and installed bpython, which can be installed with either Macports `sudo port install py27-bpython` or `pip install bpython`!

Comment: The Python package for readline has been renamed to `gnureadline`, to avoid the name conflict with stdlib readline. IPython >= 2.0 depends on this package on OS X, so `pip install --upgrade ipython` will get proper readline, and everything should be happy.

Comment: `easy_install -a readline` fixed my global python, thanks! I didn't manage to fix my virtualenv, so I blew it away and recreated it.. sorted!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind mucking around with your PYTHONPATH, here's how you can get rid of that pesky warning:

```
# move site-packages to the front of your sys.path
import sys
for i in range(len(sys.path)):
    if sys.path[i].endswith('site-packages'):
        path = sys.path.pop(i)
        sys.path.insert(0, path)
        break
```

If you're using Django, you can put this in the `ipython` method of your site-packages/django/core/management/commands/shell.py so that it runs when you run `./manage.py shell`.

Answer (score 0):

Additional note to future readers of this answer.

In my case -- running a MacPorts installation of IPython -- there were several versions of `easy_install` in /opt/local/bin/, but no non-versioned symlink pointing to the most current. Performing `easy_install-2.7 -a readline` worked.

Answer (score 0):

I am also using `brew` installed `ipython` and I had a similar issue.

```
⚡ easy_install-3.7 -a readline
Searching for readline
Reading https://pypi.org/simple/readline/
Download error on https://pypi.org/simple/readline/: unknown url type: https -- Some packages may not be found!
Couldn't find index page for 'readline' (maybe misspelled?)
Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
Reading https://pypi.org/simple/
Download error on https://pypi.org/simple/: unknown url type: https -- Some packages may not be found!
No local packages or working download links found for readline
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('readline') (--always-copy skips system and development eggs)
```

Solution:

```
⚡ brew install readline
Updating Homebrew...
Warning: readline 7.0.5 is already installed, it's just not linked
You can use `brew link readline` to link this version.
⚡ brew link readline
Warning: readline is keg-only and must be linked with --force
⚡ brew link readline --force
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/readline/7.0.5... 16 symlinks created
```

Result:

```
⚡ ipython
Python 3.7.2 (default, Dec 27 2018, 07:35:06)
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 7.2.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.
>>> ~/.pyrc loaded successfully
```