# OSX remote_api_shell.py Can no longer use arrow keys to load previously executed lines / navigate

Tags: google-app-engine

I used to be able to press up and down to cycle through previous commands that I had run in the `remote_api_shell.py`, and left and right to move the cursor within a line I was about to submit to the interactive console.

For some reason that just stopped working

Pressing up, up, down, left, right now causes the following to be appended to the current line instead:

```
^[[A^[[A^[[B^[[D^[[C
```

When I exit, I'm still able to do all this in bash. Anyone know what could cause this to stop working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like my general python interactive shell on my machine is what's having problems (similar to this issue: [Arrow keys no longer work in Python shell after upgrading Mac OS to Sierra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39807946/arrow-keys-no-longer-work-in-python-shell-after-upgrading-mac-os-to-sierra))

I did `pip install gnureadline` and if I `import gnureadline` at the start of my shell session, the arrows work again

EDIT:
simply running `brew upgrade` fixed it

Answer (score 1):

can you please explain more about your issue? what kind of enviroment that are you facing this issue in "Cloud Shell" or in "Compute Engine"?

Comment: I use App Engine. `remote_api_shell.py` is this https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/remoteapi#using_the_remote_api_shell It seems that my issue is unrelated to GCP and is a general python shell issue similar to this: 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39807946/arrow-keys-no-longer-work-in-python-shell-after-upgrading-mac-os-to-sierra